# Can the 'test question' feature be disabled in the the first posts review queue

Tags: support

I just wrote a detailed comment to a poster only to find out it was a test question and my work was in vain. I think this is silly. I don't want to spin my wheels and put thought into a comment for playing games. I am putting in my volunteer time for this to help *other people*.

Comment: There have been many complaints about review queue audits over the years.  They are a necessary evil.

Comment: What evidence do you have they are necessary in the form they are currently in?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/review-audits/info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, you are a good person and always pay attention to what you are reviewing.

However, this "test question" feature is not about **you**. It is about the countless numbers of reviewers who take the cumbersome work of walking through those review queues and up-, down-, or close vote any of those questions or answers. Such work tends to make people inattentive, and some of them sometimes may get tired and may be tempted to repeat the voting of others without reading the related post thoroughly before they vote.

To prevent this, the vendor of the SE sites decided to put in a feature to the system to motivate people to "stay awake". Sure, this can be annoying, but giving users a possibility to switch this feature off would obviously make it quite ineffective, since exactly those people for whom the feature was designed would most probably turn it off. So if you want to use the review queues, you better get used to it.

Comment: I think this could be solved by other means (analytics and machine learning) rather than penalizing the folks who write 400 words to help improve the post. I'll stay off the review queues for the time being.

Comment: @MartinK: instead of staying away from the review queues completely, I think this could be solved by other means ;-) When a question or answer in the queue looks suspiciously bad, I would recommend to open the original question thread in a separate browser tab (not just for the detection of these test question, but to get a broader view what has already been written there).